# CakePHP 4 - Ajax POST request return forbidden 403 with security disabled

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am trying to make a simple Pokemon catalogue for a school project and I want to use Ajax for the "add to cart" button. Yet, I keep getting "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)" even tho I added what is mentioned in the official doc of CakePHP to disable Security.

I know this question is asked many times but couldn't really find a working answer for 4.x. Where is my mistake ? Thanks in advance for replies

**Ajax function:**

```
function ajaxAddToBasket(poke_id){
    $.post("<?= $this->Url->build(['controller' => 'Paniers', 'action' => 'Addtobasket']) ?>",
        {
            pokemon_id: poke_id,
        },
        function(data, status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        }
    );
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function initialize(): void
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Security');
}

public function beforeFilter(EventInterface $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Security->setConfig('unlockedActions', ['addtobasket']);
}

public function addtobasket()
{

    $pokemon_id = $this->request->getData('pokemon_id');
    $user_id = $this->request->getSession()->read('user_id');

    if($pokemon_id != null && is_nan($pokemon_id)){
          /** Some to-dos here **/
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check your error/debug logs (`/logs/`) for details on what actually triggers that error/response. The security component usually triggers `400` errors, not `403`, the latter rather hints to the CSRF middleware.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the X-CSRF-Token in the header. This is how my Ajax-Request looks like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/Paniers/Addtobasket/",
  type: "POST",
  data: {"pokemon_id":poke_id},
  headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': <?= json_encode($this->request->getAttribute('csrfToken')); ?>,
  },
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(error, message) {
    console.log(error, message);
  }
});
```