# ERROR: POST http://localhost:8765/users/delete/delete8 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I'm using cakephp4. trying to add some sweetalert. Sweetalert is popping up when the delete button is clicked but when I click confirm for delete it's not deleting the data.

template/layout/Users/index.php

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Usertype</th>
    <th>Created</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>

<?php foreach ($users as $user) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?= $this->Html->link($user->username, ['action' => 'view', $user->slug]); ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?= $this->Html->tag('span', $user->utype) ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?= $user->created->format(DATE_RFC850); ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?= $this->Html->link('Edit', ['action' => 'edit', $user- 
               >slug]); ?> /
            
            <a href="#" class="delete" data-slug="<?=$user->slug? 
               >">Delete</a>
           
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

template/layout/Users/index.php

```
<script>

deletes = document.getElementsByClassName('delete');
Array.from(deletes).forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let ajax_url = $(e.target).attr('data-slug');
    
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
      icon: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
          $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/users/delete/'+ ajax_url,
            beforeSend: function(xhr){
                xhr.setRequestHeader(
                    'X-CSRF-Token',
                    <?= json_encode($this->request- 
                       >getParam('_csrfToken')); ?>
                );
            },
            success: function(response){
                if(response){
                    Swal.fire(
                        'Deleted!',
                        'Your file has been deleted.',
                        'success'
                    )
                }
                else {
                    Swal.fire({
                      icon: 'error',
                      title: 'Oops...',
                      text: 'No data deleted',
                 })
      }
            },
            error: function(e){
                console.log('error', e);
            }
          })
       
      } 
    })
  })
})
```

delete method is as follows in my UsersController.php

UsersController.php

```
public function delete($slug)
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
    $user = $this->Users->findBySlug($slug)->firstorFail();
    if ($this->Users->delete($user)) {
        $this->Flash->success("Deleted Successfully");
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
    $this->Flash->error('Unable to Delete user');
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

Route File is here
config/route.php

```
  <?php

   use Cake\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware;
   use Cake\Routing\Route\DashedRoute;
   use Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder;


  $routes->setRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);

  $routes->scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $builder) {

   $builder->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 
'display', 'home']);
  
  $builder->connect('/users/delete/{slug}', ['controller' => 'Users', 
'action' => 'delete']);

  $builder->connect('/pages/*', 'Pages::display');

  $builder->fallback();
```

});

Comment: If the errors say the same as in the title, you're most likely missing slash character `/` before the id. Pay attention to what URL are you referring to. Perhaps you could preview what's in it before sending the request? Try putting `console.log('/users/delete/'+ ajax_url)` before `Swal.fire` line.

Comment: i did console.log('/users/delete/'+ ajax_url) . and in this I'm getting this URL /users/delete/username

Username is whatever the name of the user

Comment: Can you share the routing?

Comment: routing of what?

Comment: Application routing. If you're using Cake framework, there's probably a `config/routes.php` file. I'd like to see what's the definition of this endpoint.

Comment: Added now. Please check. and WHY i'm getting NULL in csrfToken?

Comment: How do you display the users list? Can you share the list action?

Comment: Added how i add users list. in index.php file

Comment: Is this ok to not explicitly define the delete route in the `config/routes.php` file? Do you really use `xsrf`? Can you manually visit this page?

Comment: no. i can't manually visit the page

Comment: What's the error when you visit, for example, `/users/delete/dummy`? Call it with POST and DELETE methods.

Comment: ERROR: Too few arguments to function App\Controller\UsersController::delete(),

Comment: Try to define a route: `$builder->connect('/users/delete/{slug}', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'delete']);` and see what you see when you visit `/users/delete/dummy`.

Comment: same error of Too few arguments. 0 passed exactly 1 expected

Comment: Can you please update the description with a new `routes.php` file?

Comment: updated. please check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure it's the CSRF token. Try to replace

```
<?= json_encode($this->request->getParam('_csrfToken')); ?>
```

with

```
<?= json_encode($this->request->getAttribute('csrfToken')); ?>
```

Also I am not sure about your "beforeSend: function(xhr)", you can see a working ajax call example here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67253585/15256337